# InDesign GREP style Bold before tab

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, indesign-scripting, grep, bold

I have this GREP style that bolds text before a colon but I would like to do this without a colon.

I have done this as a paragraph style to apply bold to list of abbreviations.

^[^:]+

When I have replaced the : for a GREP style for tab it doesn't work but I assume I am missing something out here.

Comment: What is the GREP request you tried ? Besides, do you need GREP style here? Couldn't it be achieved with nested styles?

Comment: Just replace the colon with a tab symbol (`\t` if memory serves) in the GREP code. As Vinny says, though, a nested style would probably be better for your needs here.

Comment: I tried this \t but it didn't seem to work. but nested styles did thank you

Comment: Glad you solved your issue, but surprised that ^[^\t]+ didn't work!

Comment: I will just toss in something I recently learned--when you are using nested styles, you can place more than one element in the "after" field and it will work for any of them.  So, for example, I have a nested style that applies bold after any of these:  tab character or  :  or an M hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting your bullets manually, your GREP style would be:
^[•]
-where the "•" is the bullet character you're using. Replace that character with whatever character you want to use as a bullet.

However, the "proper" way to do this doesn't require GREP at all. I suggest you create a paragraph style that defines the bullet list and just apply your character style to the bullets under "Bullets and Numbering."